# Failed to load viewstate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, viewstate

> Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.

The page loads fine, until I include an asp panel on the page. Then I see the above error.

Can anyone think of a possible cause for this? The asp panel is empty, I've literally just created a test:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlTest"></asp:Panel>
```

And it breaks.

Comment: When are you "including" the panel?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by 'when'? If you mean when/where is it defined - on the markup of the aspx page.

Comment: Sorry, I was under the impression that it was being added dynamically somehow.  The Viewstate will fail to load correctly if you have loaded the page into the browser, then added the control into the aspx page, and then posted back to the server in the browser... it's because the controls in the ASPX are no longer the same as when the initial page was created - is this what you're doing?

Comment: Yer, you're spot on - for all the reading around this I've done - I can see that's the case. But no this is not added dynamically. It's just on the page mark up. It's strange how when the panel isn't there it loads fine.

Comment: Erm, not sure I understand **why** you're doing this? ASP.NET needs the ASPX mark-up to be the same on the post-back as it was on the initial page request.

Comment: I'm simply adding a panel to the asp page's design. I need an asp panel on the page. It wasn't there previously. So testing the page prior to adding the panel worked. I then changed the markup and re-deployed and tested again and it didn't.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15175/discussion-between-freefaller-and-deemac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is down to you changing things mid-way through the process...

When you request a page from ASP.NET, it uses the mark-up in the `.aspx` and `.ascx` files.  From this (along with lots of other things, including any dynamic controls you create in the code-behind) it creates the ViewState, which is stored in your page in a hidden field called `__VIEWSTATE`.

When you then subsequently post-back the page to the server (through a link, or a button click, etc) the server will **load** that ViewState information, and expect all the controls in the `.aspx` and `.ascx` files to be in exactly the same state.

From what I can tell from your comments, you are doing is this...

- Requesting the page from the server (which is loading the HTML, including the `__VIEWSTATE`)
- Changing the `.aspx` page on the server (in this case adding a new `<asp:Panel>`)
- Posting the page back to the server and getting an error.

In this third stage, the server is looking at the controls in the `.aspx` and looking at the information in the `__VIEWSTATE`... the error is because the controls **do not match**!
The server is not expecting to see an `<asp:Panel>` in the page, because the `__VIEWSTATE` mentions nothing about it.

---

So the solution to your problem is simply - just add the control to the `.aspx` **before** you load the page into the browser

Comment: Thanks so much for such a comprehensive answer, but forget about the fact I'm adding an asp panel to the page. The page doesn't work with the asp panel in it. At design time I'm adding the asp panel. At runtime it doesn't work. This is not being added dynamically in any way.

Comment: In that case @DeeMac, I don't understand what is going on... if the Panel is there when you initially request the page and nothing has changed in the `.aspx` when you post-back, then there must be something else changing for the viewstate to become invalid.

Comment: Strange isn't it. I'm assuming, by the very definition of view state, that it has no recollection of the page's previous markup when there wasn't a panel present - so I don't know 'what viewstate' it's comparing it to.

Comment: Sorry @Dee, but you appear to be contradicting yourself again... what do you mean "previous markup when there wasn't a panel present"? You're making it sound like the viewstate is being created based on a page **without** the panel, and then being loaded on the post-back against a page **with** the panel

Comment: @Dee, just to get a stupid question out of the way, please can confirm that you're **not** using a "pre-built" piece of HTML that you're posting back to the server - something that has been grabbed from a previous version of the HTML and now being sent to the server with the updated page?

Comment: forget the fact I am 'adding' an asp panel. This is not being added dynamically. I have VS open, the page has no asp panel. I debug it, it's fine. I close IE. I add an asp panel to the page in VS, I debug again, it doesn't work. I can't phrase it any differently I'm sorry. It's added at design time - I don't know how else to put it.

Comment: @DeeMac, does it do it with any other control?

Comment: No, it seems to be fine with any other control.

Comment: Really sorry @DeeMac, you have a real doozy there - I have absolutely no idea why it is failing... I certainly cannot replicate it

Comment: @DeeMac Have you found what the problem was and how to fix it?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter - this was a long time ago now, but I recall it being due to changes I was making to the DOM in between AJAX requests. The viewstate that was sent back and forth was modified so that it no longer met the expectation of the server. Sorry I can't remember any more details.

Answer (score 2):

You need to close the panel with `</asp:Panel>`

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlTest">
</asp:Panel>
```

create your dynamic controls on page init

for more info
http://geekswithblogs.net/FrostRed/archive/2007/02/17/106547.aspx

and here some more info
http://blog.typps.com/2008/01/failed-to-load-viewstate-typical.html

Comment: My apologies, that was just written (lazily) in the OP for discussion purposes (to show the panel had no contents), I did actually close it properly -  I've edited the OP. +1.

Answer (score 0):

To supress this error (ViewState will be loaded partically):

```
public partial class MyClass: System.Web.UI.Page
{ 
     bool StateFail;

     protected  override object LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() {
        if (StateFail) return null;
        return base.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium();
       }

    protected override void OnInitComplete(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnInitComplete(e);
        if (!IsPostBack) return;
        try
        {
            typeof(System.Web.UI.Page).GetMethod("LoadAllState", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(this, new object[0]);
        } catch { StateFail = true; }
        }
}
```

}